# mailgun api didn't throw any exception neither it's sending any mails

Tags: c#, smtp, mailgun

I am trying to send mails through C# RestClient and it didn't give any errors and when I open my mail my inbox is still empty.

```
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.mailgun.net/v2");
 client.Authenticator =
                    new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                               APIkey);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
                    request.AddParameter("domain",
                                        domain, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                    request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
                    request.AddParameter("from", from);
                    request.AddParameter("to", email);
                    request.AddParameter("subject", subject);
                    request.AddParameter("text", txt);
                    request.AddParameter("html", html);
```

It's give me statusCode OK, Content-Length 23. I tried to change the v2 to v3 but doesn't change anything. When I try to put domain it doesn't work. I am currently setting empty string to domain.

Please someone check this code. Any other way to check why it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: @mjwills please check my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I means "UnAuthenticated", "FORBIDDEN" Happen in result

Comment: @mjwills it is "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/messages"

Comment: Shouldn't the domain name be before /messages (https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api)?

Comment: I am still not sure what domain I need to enter. The uri I am showing you is one when it's return OK (200) and not send any mail. (this case I was sending empty string). If I send something in domain it's giving those exception I was talking earlier.

Comment: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain

Comment: Generally, the "Forbidden" response occurs whenever the domain you are using isn't apart of the same account as the API key you are using. Make sure you use one of the domains on your Mailgun account in the {domain} parameter.